# Varchar date conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My date field has value format to be : Feb 15 2019. Is there a way to convert this to MMDDYYYY format?

Desired output: 02152019

Query I tried: `SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)` - this query is showing YYYYMMDD format :(

Any help?

Comment: Store dates as date/time types.  Do not store them as strings!

Comment: Try this, select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),101),'/','')

Comment: Your application is to take care about format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select format( convert(date, 'Feb 15 2019'), 'MMddyyyy')

-- results to: 02152019


-- But again, your application is to take care about format!!!
```

Comment: @SalmanA,  to be sure that "Feb 15 2019" will be parsed. But perhaps it is redundant measure in this case, because Feb is literal representation of the month. Point taken, thanks, dateformat to be removed

Answer (score 2):

Try this query,

> select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),101),'/','')

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Select convert(varchar(12), convert(date, 'Feb 15 2019'), 112)
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') AS [MMDDYYYY]
```

This will give output - `20190215`.

You can pass different value like 101. For different output see [Here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).